# How can I get the connection string in vba from the linked tables in access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I have this linked tables on my access and I want to get the connection of it

Here is the screenshot

[image]

In my vba I tried this code but does not work because my stored procedure does not execute

```
Dim adocmd As New ADODB.Command

DoCmd.Maximize
adocmd.ActiveConnection = Application.CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString
  adocmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
adocmd.CommandText = "spr_DECSBillingSchedule"
adocmd.CommandTimeout = 0
On Error Resume Next
adocmd.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
Set adocmd = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
```

How can I possibly fix this issue? thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your issue please mark as answered, if not what further issue are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions for tables are stored in a system table called MSysObjects, the connection string is in field `Connect`. You can access this table to get the connection string as and when you want to run the sproc (you'll need to reference a table you know is in the same database, I have front ends linked to multiple databases), though as the connection string does not change you may be better to set it to a global variable or just hard code it in (which i have fallen into the habit of doing).

**NOTE: This is as per MS Access 2007, it is the only one I have installed**

Below is an example of a function I use to execute a sproc, the sproc returns a value to confirm it has completed successfully, which is returned in @Ret. Hope this helps.

```
Function LogImportFile(strFile As String) As Long
On Error GoTo Err_Handle_LogImportFile


Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=[Server];DATABASE= _
    [DatabaseName];Trusted_Connection=Yes"
    ' The above is for linking to a SQL Server table using a DSN less connection
    ' which I would highly recommend (DSN less) if you plan to distribute your
    ' database

cnn.Open cnn.ConnectionString

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "cmsUser.usp_LogImportFile"
cmd.CommandTimeout = 0

Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@FileName", adVarChar, adParamInput, _
    200, strFile)
cmd.Parameters.Append param
Set param = cmd.CreateParameter("@Ret", adInteger, adParamOutput)
cmd.Parameters.Append param


cmd.Execute

LogImportFile = cmd.Parameters("@Ret")


Exit_Proc:
Set cnn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set param = Nothing

Exit Function

Err_Handle_LogImportFile:
    Msgbox "LogImportFile - " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    LogImportFile = -1
    GoTo Exit_Proc
End Function
```